# Eclipse ADT Juno .JTDS is not established and it keeps returning " Charset 0x0904000128/Cp850 is not supported by the JVM." Jtds 1.3.0

Tags: android, jdbc, jvm, jtds

I had tried the codes below and it keeps returning null in the catch exception. May I know why and how do I fix this?

```
Connection conn = null;
try
{
    //String driver = "";
    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    String connString ="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://hostNameA/databaseNameAAA;integratedSecurity=true";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, username, password);
    Log.e(TAG,"DB Connection Established");
    conn.close();

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.e(TAG,"ERROR: Exception Caught! - " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thank you.

EDIT:
I am using jtds-1.3.1.jar
Everytime it comes to the line 
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, username, password);

an error will be caught in the catch and it will display as

ERROR: Exception Caught! - null

and now I had replaced the jtds-1.3.1.jar with jtds-1.3.0.jar file and now I am getting this error

"ERROR: Exception Caught! - Charset 0x0904000128/Cp850 is not supported by the JVM."

EDIT2:

I had tested these codes in JAVA (desktop) and it works fine with it, it is able to connect into the database and retrieve all the data from the server but when I use it in async task in android I get the "Charset is not supported by the JVM".

How do I fix this?
I had tried re-installing the JDK and it does not work. It is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

*"Charset 0x0904000128/Cp850 is not supported by the JVM."*

I found the same error message in a forum thread [here](http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1772). The response was

> This problem is due to the JVM installed on your server.
>   It's a limited language-only package (like US/English-only package).
>
> You have to change the JVM to resolve this problem.

followed by

> issue is solved by reinstallaing JVM with complete language package

Since code page 850 is an older DOS version of Latin1 (ref: [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850)) you might also try changing the source encoding of your project to Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1 and see if your current JVM can handle it before downloading and installing another JVM.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I appreciate it. May I know how to change the source encoding of the project to Windows-1252 or ISO-8859? Is it something like this ? String connString ="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://X.X.X.X:1433/DBname;instance=SQLEXPRESS;integratedSecurity=true; user=testUser; password=TestPass;useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8";?

Comment: By the way, I had updated the Java from version 6 to version 7, and I still get the same error